# Ionic Framework: Showing PDF's offline on android devices

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, pdf, ionic-framework

I have been trying to get PDF's to be displayed in ionic on android only.

I have a server where I host the PDF's and by using the ngCordova plugins i have managed to get the PDF's downloading off my server onto the *cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory* on my phone.

I should mention that the PDF's have to be private and should not be accessible from the documents or a file-manager app on the device.

Im also using the [$cordovaInAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) plugin for google login and the documentation states that it should also work for opening PDF's in a new tab. If i set the targetPath of the *open* function to a PDF on my server then the pdf opens correctly with no problems.

I know the download functionality is working correctly as i have moved the download location to a public area of the phone and opened the PDF from there using the system PDF viewer.

Im not sure what im doing wrong exactly and any help would be greatly appreciated.
The code below is the controller running the download, file checking and the opening of the file.

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module ('myApp')

.controller ("VideoCtrl", ['$cordovaInAppBrowser', '$cordovaFile', '$cordovaFileTransfer', function ($cordovaInAppBrowser, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

  this.downloadDocument = function (file, language) {
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid ()) {
      var path = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory;
      var server = "http://myServer/files/";

      var downloadPath = server + language + file;
      var targetPath = path.docs + language + file;
      var options = {
        location: 'no',
        clearcache: 'yes',
        toolbar: 'yes'
      };

      $cordovaFile.checkFile(path.docs + language, file)
      .then(function (success) {
        console.log('file exists', targetPath);
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(targetPath, '_blank', options);

      }, function (error) {

        console.log("file doesn't exists");
        $cordovaFileTransfer.download (downloadPath, targetPath, {}, true).then (
          function (result) {
            console.log('downloaded');
            $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(targetPath, '_blank', options);
          }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }, function (progress) {
            console.log((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100);
          }
        );
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="documentHolder padding">
  <div class="button button-block button-dark icon icon-left ion-document-text" ng-click="_video.downloadDocument()">
    Download Document
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: android webview doesn't render pdf files. To open an external app try with _system option instead of _blank. _blank will only work on ios as the ios webview renders pdf files.

Comment: @jcesarmobile i have tried doing that however when it tries to load the file the pdf viewer opens and then instantly closes again, using an alternative pdf does the same thing.